# Using Windows Workflow to control flow in the User Interface

Tags: c#, architecture, user-interface, prism, workflow-foundation

When Windows Workflow first came out there were some articles that suggested that it could also be used to control the flow in the UI. One example is [this](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34732) one.

But I have not been able to find any newer articles about this.

So the question: Has anyone had any success with this approach? Or was it one of those things that turned out not to be such a good idea after all?

Our client is WPF with Prism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the type of site. Microsoft built their [support site](http://support.microsoft.com) using a [Wizard activity structure](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-233b5e3c) due to the complexity of the rules and to enable business users to directly manage the control flow. I have not found a good use case for actually using WF to control the presentation or business rules. It is much easier to use a well-known pattern (MVC / MVVM) to construct your application. For simple site flows - you are probably better off without the added complexity.

Answer (score 0):

All of our pageflow for EmpowerID our Identity Management and app dev platform is handle in Window Workflow
Links:
http://www.youtube.com/empowerID
http://www.thedotnetfactory.com/workflow_studio.php
http://wiki.thedotnetfactory.com/display/public/WFS/Creating+the+Leave+Request+Workflow
Patrick